# retrieve integer name in shortest.path function of igraph

Tags: igraph

First, I have a shortest path matrix generated with igraph (shortest path)
When I want to retreive the node names with "get.shortest.path" it just brings me the number of each column and not its name:

```
       [,a] [,b] [,c] [,d] [,e] [,f] [,g] [,h] [,i] [,j]
 [a,]    0    1    2    3    4    5    4    3    2     1
 [b,]    1    0    1    2    3    4    5    4    3     2
 [c,]    2    1    0    1    2    3    4    5    4     3
 [d,]    3    2    1    0    1    2    3    4    5     4
 [e,]    4    3    2    1    0    1    2    3    4     5
 [f,]    5    4    3    2    1    0    1    2    3     4
 [g,]    4    5    4    3    2    1    0    1    2     3
 [h,]    3    4    5    4    3    2    1    0    1     2
 [i,]    2    3    4    5    4    3    2    1    0     1
 [j,]    1    2    3    4    5    4    3    2    1     0
```

then:

```
get.shortest.paths(g, 5, 1)
```

the answer is:

```
[[1]]
[1] 5 4 3 2
```

I want the node names not their numbers. Is there any solution? I checked vpath, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick for me:

```
paths <- get.shortest.paths(g, 5, 1)$vpath
names <- V(g)$name
lapply(paths, function(x) { names[x] })
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a slightly simpler solution that does not use lapply:

```
paths <- get.shortest.paths(g, 5, 1)
V(g)$name[paths$vpath[[1]]]
```

Comment: @OsmanKhalid Apologies, that should have been 'paths', not 'p'.  I have fixed it.  Thank you.